# Create a raycast 3D

Tags: java, math, 3d, raycasting

today I try to make a raycast for detect the entity who I see.

So I make a function which return an Entity:

```
public Entity rayTrace()
{
    if(entity instanceof EntityPlayer)
    {
        Vector3f cam = ((EntityPlayer)this.entity).getCameraPos();
        float distanceZ = (float)(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(this.entity.getRotY())) * 0.3f);
        float distanceX = (float)(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(this.entity.getRotY())) * 0.3f);
        Vector3f playerDirection = new Vector3f(cam.x + distanceX, cam.y, cam.z + distanceZ);
        Vector3f playerView = MathHelper.coordinate(cam, playerDirection);

        for(Entity entity : Entity.entityList)
        {

            for(int k = 0; !entity.hitBox.collideWithVector(playerView); k++)
            {
                playerView = MathHelper.coordinate(cam.translate(k, 0, k), playerDirection.translate(k, 0, k));
                if(entity.hitBox.collideWithVector(playerView))
                {
                    System.out.println(entity);
                    return entity;
                }
                if(k>10)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

the func MathHelper.coordinate:

```
public static Vector3f coordinate(Vector3f vec1, Vector3f vec2)
{
    return new Vector3f(vec2.x - vec1.x, vec2.y - vec1.y, vec2.z - vec1.z);
}
```

and the collideWithVector():

```
public boolean collideWithVector(Vector3f vec)
{
    return(vec.x > this.minX && vec.x < this.maxX && vec.y > this.minY && vec.y < this.maxY && vec.z > this.minZ && vec.z < this.maxX);
}
```

my entityList isn't empty (I have 1 entity in this list), and this code return null, k always is bigger than 10.

If you now how to resolve my problem, say it :), And if you need more code/log say it

Good bye guy.

**[edit1]**

I try to draw vertors on my client app with this code:

```
 float k = 1;

private void test()
{
    Vector3f cam = ClientMain.camera.getPosition();
    float distanceZ = (float)(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(this.player.getRotY())) * 0.3f);
    float distanceX = (float)(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(this.player.getRotY())) * 0.3f);
    Vector3f playerDirection = new Vector3f(cam.x + distanceX, cam.y, cam.z + distanceZ);
    Vector3f playerView = new Vector3f(playerDirection.x * k - cam.x * k, playerDirection.y * k - cam.y * k, playerDirection.z * k - cam.z * k);

    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_LINES);
    GL11.glVertex3f(player.getPosition().x, player.getPosition().y, player.getPosition().z);
    GL11.glVertex3f(player.getPosition().x + cam.x, player.getPosition().y + cam.y, player.getPosition().z + cam.z);
    GL11.glEnd();

    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_LINES);
    GL11.glVertex3f(player.getPosition().x, player.getPosition().y, player.getPosition().z);
    GL11.glVertex3f(player.getPosition().x + playerDirection.x, player.getPosition().y + playerDirection.y, player.getPosition().z + playerDirection.z);
    GL11.glEnd();

    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_LINES);
    GL11.glVertex3f(player.getPosition().x, player.getPosition().y, player.getPosition().z);
    GL11.glVertex3f(player.getPosition().x + playerView.x, player.getPosition().y + playerView.y, player.getPosition().z + playerView.z);
    GL11.glEnd();
    k+=0.1f;

    System.out.println("cam: " + cam + " \nplayerDirection: " + playerDirection + " \nplayerView: " + playerView + " \ndZ: " + distanceZ + " dX: " + distanceX);

 //   System.out.println("DRAW: " + k);
    if(k > 5000)
    {
        System.out.println("RESET");
        k = 0;
    }
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

but the line was draw strangely: [image]

the vector was draw at the left-top

Comment: 1. try to draw your vectors  to see if they have correct values, 2. I do not see any code/formula for perpendicular distance of point and half axis needed this to work ... so what approach you are using? (I see only 3D volume matching but without more info is hard to say what is the purpose of it)

Comment: if the direction of the vectors does not match what you have expecting then you have bug somewhere. I bet it is you camera direction (different that you think it is) or if you are using euler angles then may be you have different order of transforms somewhere ... try to make some example scenarios like put player and camera to known position orientation and do the draw again and see the difference may be you will found something (like rotation by 90 degree ...) also try turning player and see if the vectr is turning how it should  ...These bugs are very hard to find

Comment: I don't think is a bug of camera's rotation because I use this rotation for my player's movement and I don't have any bug

Comment: nobody have an idea?

Comment: What is the issue in your image ? the black occlusion on the left ? the aliasing in the pattern near horizon ? something else ?